# How can I use the listings package with more than one language?

Tags: listings

I am writing a book that will include code in two languages (R and SAS). I know I could use `\verbatim` or `\alltt` to set the code sections, but the `listings` package has some nice features.

Is there a way to use `listings` with two languages?

Comment: Sure, why not. You only need to set the language in the optional argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have different options for the two languages, you can define two styles, and use the appropriate option `style=...` of your `lstlisting` environments.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{SAS}{
  language=SAS,  
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  } 
\lstdefinestyle{R}{
  language=R,
  breaklines=true,  
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}
\begin{document} 
Example of SAS code:
\begin{lstlisting}[style=SAS]
data myoutput;
set myinput;
if myvar = "OK" then output;
run;
\end{lstlisting}
Example of R code:
\begin{lstlisting}[style=R]
# I don't know R, code copied from http://www.rexamples.com/2/Functions
Square <- function(x) {
  return(x^2)
}

print(Square(4))
print(Square(x=4)) # same thing
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]